# jQuery $.get not working after clicking on the link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code that gets the latest topics from my forum and display on the page, but if I click on the HOME button, that links back to the same page, it does not show the content on the page. But if I click on the browser refresh button it works.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('getLatestTopic.cfm', function(data) {
     $("#latest").html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to open the browser debugger? What error do you get? The code looks fine as it is so there must be something wrong somewhere else...

Comment: sure this isn't some caching issue? `ctrl+r` or `ctrl+f5`

Comment: Probably `getLatestTopic.cfm` has all HTML `<html>` `<body>` tags, and you are amending it to `#latest`, this could be another reason for your problem

Comment: the getLatestTopic.cfm has not html tags on it... I'm using with jQuery mobile... could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

First, when using the jQuery Mobile framework, you are supposed to use the 'pageinit' event of the page your are loading rather that the $(document).ready(). The reason for this is that jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to load the contents of each defined page into the DOM as you navigate around. This means that the DOM ready handler only fires for pages loaded directly (like the first page you load or any page that you reload by using the browser refresh button for example).

```
$( '#myPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
   $.get('getLatestTopic.cfm', function(data) {
      $("#latest").html(data);
   });
});
```

Doing this will ensure that a get request is sent to 'getLatestTopic.cfm' when '#myPage' has been created and inserted into the DOM (happens once). This means that if the '#latest' element is located inside '#myPage', it will contain the data returned from 'getLatestTopic.cfm' and it will be cached in the DOM. If you want to execute the get request every time you load "myPage", you can use the 'pagebeforeshow' event instead.

```
$( '#myPage' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
   // This code executes every time the '#myPage' is navigated to, before it is shown.
});
```